# Using jQuery inside a PHP page while using a HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use jQuery UI widgets such as datepicker and selectable inside my page book.php. Inside the page I'm using a HTML form. For some reason, when I try to use datepicker and selectable, it's just not working?? On previous pages I have gotten jQuery to work, but for some reason it won't work on this page!

This is my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="homepage_loggedin_book_andrea.php">

      Your appointment ID is: 
      <?php
      $test = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM appointments"), 0);
      echo $test;
      ?>
      <br>
      <p>Please enter the appointment ID: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" name="id"></p>

       <p>Date: <input type="text" id="#datepicker" name="slot_date"></p>

       <br>
       Blue dots are lines when Andrea is unavailable.
       <img src="Timetable_andrea.jpg" width="400" height="251" alt=""/><br>
       <label for="slot_line" name="slot_line" id="selectable">Select a line</label>
       <ol id="selectable" name="slot_line">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Line 7</li>
</ol>
<br>
<br>

     <p>Reason for appointment: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['reason']; ?>" name="reason" style="width: 300px;"></p>

        <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-book">Book</button>
            </div>

            </form>
```

As you can see, I just the ID datepicker and selectable where I want the jQuery to work. I have the jQuery code on a seperate page (which I have targeted in my this HTML page)

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#menu" ).selectmenu();
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
 });
```

All I need to work is the datepicker and selectable in my PHP code? I'm not sure as to why it's not working.. Someone please help!

Comment: For one thing `id="#datepicker"` you need to remove the `#` from it. However, I don't see where you declared the `menu` ID. Check for errors and look at your console. You should have seen some type of warning for it.

Comment: I got rid of the #, but it made no difference? In my jQuery page it says I need to use the 'use strict' statement but when I use that it still makes no difference. And on this page, I'm not using the menu